# Se puede llamar un web panel desde un panel en Angular?

Tags: java, .net, genexus, genexus18, generador

Estoy tratando de llamar un web panel desde un panel generado por angular y NO lo carga, no hace el llamado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Podes llama un webpanel desde un Panel Angular. Es equivalente a hacer un redirect, es decir, te saca de la app Angular.

Una opcion es, con la URL usar el metodo Link, algo asi:

```
Link(<url_webpanel>)
```

Un concepto que es importante en esto es que, aunque sea un webpanel en la misma kb lo que estas llamando, conceptualmente son dos aplicaciones distintas.